# The hard-to-understand chain

Tags: riddle, knowledge

I have a chain.

I can extend this chain indefinitely.

For beginners, this chain is hard to understand.

They call it magical, yet it is not in reality.

I used to only declare.

But with this chain, I can finally command.

[Maybe, this chain is made from Io.]

What am I and what is this chain?

Subtle Hint:

> Though there is only one **kind** of the chain, it comes in various **types**. Three types are mentioned in the text.

Moderate Hint:

> The chain can be so many things. It can be a writer, it can be a reader, it can be a parser, it can store states, and many other things.

Moderate Hint 2:

> There is a sugar. The chain can be **done**.

Decisive Hint:

> I am in seven letters. The chain is in five letters.

Decisive Hint 2:

> I start with 'H'. The chain starts with 'M'.

Decisive Hint 3:

> I end with 'l'. The chain ends with 'd'.

Comment: I'm thinking rot13(uggcf://ra.jvxvcrqvn.bet/jvxv/Punva-bs-erfcbafvovyvgl_cnggrea), but I'm not seeing a clear mapping.

Comment: @Avi Nah, that's irrelevent. (On the second thought, that *might be*  somehow relevent.)

Comment: Good to know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are

> The [Haskell programming Language](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_(programming_language))

And the chain is

> A [monad](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming))

Comment: Correct! I'd like you to explain each clues.

Answer (score 1):

Since It would declare earlier but can now command others

> Is I a programmer and the chain is a programming language or a computer ?

Comment: rot13(Ab. V nz n cebtenzzvat ynathntr.)

Comment: Ok . would keep it in mind

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> A program's compilation chain?

I'll add more details if this is correct....mainly due to actually having to study to do this.

Comment: Close. Very close.

Comment: rot13(Lbh ner evtug gb guvax vg eryngrq gb cebtenzzvat.)

Answer (score 0):

> For beginners, this chain is hard to understand.

it's a somewhat advanced concept

> I used to only declare. But with this chain, I can finally command.

.

> What you say can now be commmands to another process

.

> [Maybe, this chain is made from Io.]

actually it is made from

> I/O  input and output

.

> What am I and what is this chain?

.

> You a process producing output, and the chain is a shell pipeline

Comment: Another close answer!

Comment: rot13(Lbhe vagrecergvba bs "Vb" vf pbeerpg, ohg vg vf whfg n glcr bs gur punva.)